# Empty block and blocks with ; only in if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

I've been testing myself with a test in Java SE 7 Programmer 1 study guide. There is this question about if statements. It asks which option won't compile:

```
>      a) if(true) ;
>      b) if(true) {}
>      c)if(true) {;}
>      d)if(true) {;;}
>      e)if (true) ;{};
>      f) all of them will compile
```

The answer is f. And I can't understand or explain why answers c,d and e will compile.

Comment: Have you tried putting these lines into an IDE?

Comment: Why do you think answers c, d and e would be incorrect?

Comment: Because a `;` on its own is legal (if unhelpful) in Java.

Comment: @TheLostMind yes, and they will compile. The question is why

Comment: @Nazerke - `;` is a valid empty statement. `{}` represents valid empty blocks

Comment: @khelwood - That actually depends on where `;` is present. Inside a while block it is helpful (in a *negative* way of course :P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that `;` counts as a valid standalone statement and `{}` is a valid standalone code block.  So when when any of these are parsed, they will be valid code.  They just don't do anything.

Comment: Okay I c. The idea that ; is a valid standalone statement is new to me. But then why e is correct. e)if (true) ;{};   Can there be any statement between if(boolean) and {block}?

Comment: e) is a little tricky.  It's actually more than one statement:  an if statement (`if (true) ;`) and then more code (`{};`)

Answer (score 2):

The options C,D and E are valid. They are all *ignored* by the *compiler*.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(true) {;} // a valid empty statement inside a code block --> valid
    if(true){;;} // 2 valid empty statements inside a code block --> valid
    if(true);{}; // a valid empty statement followed by an empty codeblock followed by another valid empty / dummy statement.
}
```

They all do **NOTHING** . The compiler removes them all.

Note : `if(true)` is ignored by the compiler but `while(true)` is not and will be present as a `goto` statement in the byte code.

Bytecode  :

```
 public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
   flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
   Code:
     stack=0, locals=1, args_size=1
        0: return   --> Where on earth are my if conditions?
```